# add active to collapsible nav-link

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

The code was initially designed with `data-toggle="tab"` but I replaced it to collapse. It worked as I wanted. I need to to include active to `nav-link` class for css redesign purposes. I tried couple of jQuery but none seem to work.

```js
$('.nav .nav-item .nav-link').click(function(){
    $('.nav .nav-item .nav-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" style="width: 100%;margin: auto;padding: 0px;" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#dashboard-1" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse"> <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i> Dashboard </a></li> 
   <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#schedule-1"  role="tab" data-toggle="collapse"> <i class="material-icons">schedule</i>  Schedule  </a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#tasks-1"          role="tab" data-toggle="collapse"> <i class="material-icons">list</i>      List      </a></li>
  </ul>
    <div class="tab-content tab-space"> 
 <div class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="dashboard-1">Collaboratively</div>
 <div class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="schedule-1"> Efficiently    </div>
 <div class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="tasks-1"> Completely     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nsv8po1/1/) for you. Its work perfect as per your question.

```js
 $('li').click(function() {
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
```

```css
.active{
background-color:yellow;
font-size:25px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" style="width: 100%;margin: auto;padding: 0px;" role="tablist">
       <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#dashboard-1" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse"> <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i> Dashboard </a></li> 
       <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#schedule-1"  role="tab" data-toggle="collapse"> <i class="material-icons">schedule</i>  Schedule  </a></li>
       <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#tasks-1"          role="tab" data-toggle="collapse"> <i class="material-icons">list</i>      List      </a></li>
      </ul>
        <div class="tab-content tab-space"> 
     <div class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="dashboard-1">Collaboratively</div>
     <div class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="schedule-1"> Efficiently    </div>
     <div class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="tasks-1"> Completely     </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it worked with replacing " li " with " a". I need now your help to check if $(this) is already active, I want to remove it. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

no change to HTML code. the java script basically check if clicked nav pill has an active state, it will remove it otherwise it will assign active class and remove active class in others.

```js
 $('a').click(function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
 $('a.active').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: i've already do it in my code.You do not need to use `if else...` for that.