# JQuery active class a tag don't execute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a navbar with a dynamic active menu using jquery. 
I have already the code and it is working except on 1 things

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('ul li a').click(function(){
            $('li a').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            return false;
          });
}); 

 <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a>
 </li>
```

The above code work and I get a active menu when I click on a `<a>` tag.
Only the `<a>` tag won't work. And when I commend out the return false the `<a>` tag is working but I don't get a active class.
I also tried `e.preventDefault()` but then I prevent my a tag to execute. I know that `return false` in `preventDefault()` the function has to stop executing on my a tag. But how can I work around that ?

I hope that I get my active class dynamic and my a tag is still executing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923964/add-active-to-collapsible-nav-link/51924472#51924472

Comment: you are going to a new page so the state is lost after the page is loaded, you need send the state to the new page

Comment: @madalinivascu Please add your comment as an answer so it can be chosen as the correct answer and/or upvoted.

Comment: @gibberish this question is a duplicate, i think someone should close it

Comment: @madalinivascu The problem with giving a correct answer as a comment is that others without your integrity will take your words and submit them as the answer - and that will be the only answer, and it will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to a new page so the state is lost after the page is loaded, you need send the state to the new page, you can use for that [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          var state = localStorage.getItem('activeLink');//get the state from localstorage
          if(state !== null && state.length) {
           $('.nav-link[href="'+state+'"]').addClass('active');//set the active class

          }
          $('ul li a').click(function(){
            $('li a').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            localStorage.setItem('activeLink',$(this).attr('href'));//save the clicked link in localstorage
          });
}); 

 <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: @just4you Notice how madalinivescu is using [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to save the href of the clicked button, and retrieving it on page load to correctly set the button state.

Comment: @madalinivascu I I get this error ``` Cannot read property 'length' of null ``` I it about this line ``` if(state.length) { ``` I think that there is no active class ?

Comment: thanks it works like a charm. Also your link to local storage is great +

Comment: @just4you glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

How about this one liner?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a[href='"+window.location.pathname+"']").prop("href", "#")
        .addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

You don't have to wait for the click event anymore.
Above code will try to find the url in the dom and will add `active` class and disables the url routing by replacing its actual url to `#`.

Place the above code before the ending body tag and ... voila.

Comment: do you have your code tested ? By my it isn't working it doesn't give a error or anything ? If you tested it I then I know that I did something wrong.